# onItemClicked() in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-listview, onitemclicklistener

I created a ListView within a fragment and populated it with data from a class called Workout within the onStart() method. I set an Adapter and the list shows up fine. I would like to now be able to get the value of the specific row that the user clicks but am unable to implement an onItemClicked() method. Does anyone know how I can get this value? Thank you.

```
public class WorkoutListFragment extends Fragment {
static interface WorkoutListListener{
    void itemClicked(long id);
}
private WorkoutListListener listener;
private ListView workoutList;
private LayoutInflater inflate;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    inflate = inflater;
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_workout_list, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    this.listener = (WorkoutListListener)activity;
}

@Override//ISSUE IS IN HERE
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    View view = getView();
    String[]names = new String[Workout.workouts.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
        names[i] = Workout.workouts[i].getName();
    }
    if (view!=null){
        workoutList = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        ArrayAdapter<String>adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(inflate.getContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,names);
        workoutList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    //HOW CAN I NOW GET THE VALUE OF THE ITEM CLICKED?
    // I TRIED THIS BUT IT'S NOT RECOGNIZED
    workoutList.setOnClickListener(new onItemClickListener);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
workoutList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
          // the 'position' argument is the position you are looking for
     }
});
```

**EDIT:**

I noticed that you are not initializing the `workoutList` listView. You should do that in the **OnCreateView** method:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_workout_list, container, false);
    workoutList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.workoutListView); // assuming that your listView's id is "@+id/workoutListView"
    return view;
}
```